# PropertyAnimation called in a loop execute only once - QML

Tags: qml

I have a page with 4 cards placed on the top of each other. I want to add  short-cuts to access each card without clicking on the button "next". I have an animation to make the card slide.
I would like to call this animation several time in one click but when I call the animation.start(), it seems to execute only one.
Here my code :

```
MyShortcut{
          onClicked:{
             for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
                   var actualCardSelected = actualCard()
                   console.log("clique clique, card selected ", actualCardSelected)

                       // while(actualCardSelected !== 1 ){
                            if(datePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
                            }else if(timePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
                                previousCard = datePickerContainer
                                margin = 0
                                animateGoLeft.start()
                            }else if(globalConfigContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
                                if(currentTimeDate.checked){
                                    previousCard = datePickerContainer
                                    timePickerContainer.x = (pageGeneralSettings.width - maxCardWidth)/2 - 10
                                    margin = 0
                                }else{
                                    previousCard = timePickerContainer
                                    margin = 10
                                }
                                animateGoLeft.start()
                            }else if(visualConditionsContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
                                previousCard = globalConfigContainer
                                buttonRight.text="Next"
                                margin = 20
                                animateGoLeft.start()
                            }
                        }
                        //}
                    }
                }


PropertyAnimation{
    id:animateGoRight
    target:selectedCard
    loops:1
    properties:"x"
    to:pageGeneralSettings.width
    easing.type: Easing.InQuint;
    duration:500
}
PropertyAnimation{
    id:animateGoLeft
    target:previousCard
    loops:1
    properties:"x"
    to:(pageGeneralSettings.width-dp(320) - maxCardWidth)/2 - margin
    easing.type: Easing.OutQuint;
    duration:500
}

    function actualCard(){
        var result
        if(datePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            result = 1
        }else if(timePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            result = 2
        }else if(globalConfigContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            result = 3
        }else if(visualConditionsContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            result = 4
        }else{
            result = 0
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably get more answers if you post simplified code. Personally I can't be bothered looking through that much code.

Comment: Ok, I will simplify it

Comment: It still needs to be able to run, though.